# ¿Cómo se llama la acción contraria a "seleccionar"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Estaba comentando el código asociado a un `<select multiple>` y me di cuenta de que la palabra **deseleccionar** no pertenece a nuestro idioma.

¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna forma de designar la acción de "hacer algo para que lo que está seleccionado deje de estarlo"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al parecer, RAE sí acepta "*[deseleccionar](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/340020730014085120?lang=en)*" (el cuál también he oído y visto que se usa) así como las siguientes alternativas:

- Borrar selección
- Eliminar selección
- Dejar de seleccionar